# Is there a way to use a second microphone to control a noise gate?

Tags: microphone, noise-reduction

I have a condenser microphone that I use as my main computer microphone, but it has an 8 pickup pattern and tends to, e.g., pick up my keyboard.

Is there a way to set a noise gate to use the crap headset microphone I have for controlling the noise gate on the condenser microphone using a VST?

Comment: You don't tell us what software & routing capabilities you have but, yes, in theory. You'll need a gate with sidechain & a DAW etc capable of using sidechaining.

Comment: Yes, you should tell use what you are using (which DAW if any, other software), what is your aim (recording, live broadcasting...) It is not clear you are using a computer anyway. From this point it is difficult to help.